# What should I do to avoid overloading a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676998/recording-3rd-party-http-responses-with-cartridge-and-midje-in-clojure) about a library called Cartridge, but when I came to add the `cartridge` tag, I discovered that there's a shopping-cart application built in Django that already uses that tag.  I don't have the rep to make a new `cartridge-clojure` tag, so what's the best approach?  In this instance I've overloaded the tag, but that seems like a Bad Thing to do.

I couldn't find guidelines on this particular issue, but please point me in the right direction if I've missed something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should ask someone to create the tag for you. As you just did. Excellent!

Comment: Great, thanks, just what I needed!  In general though, presumably it's not desirable for everyone who needs a new tag to be spamming meta, and a kindly gentleman with lots of rep such as yourself may not always see a question needing a new tag.  What do you think the best approach is in general?

Comment: @Conan it's rare enough to be just fine and not be considered "spamming meta". High rep users roam this place 24/7, not to mention moderators and the dev team. :)

Comment: I've got my answer then, thanks!